# Zope 2: How to properly "browser:page" to make a page available everywhere?

Tags: zope

Let's assume I have a sample application with following classes:

```py
##
## impelementation/SampleApp.py
##
class SampleApp: # inherits from required classes
    """ """
    implements(ISampleApp)
    # ...
    index_html = PageTemplateFile('templates/index.pt')


##
## implementation/SampleAppUser.py
##
class SampleAppUser: # inherits from required classes
    """ """
    implements(ISampleAppUser)
    # ...
    index_html = PageTemplateFile('templates/user_index.pt')

manage_addSampleAppUserForm = PageTemplateFile('manage_addSampleUserUserForm.pt')
```

Now I'd like to able to link to sign-in form (`manage_addSampleUserUserForm.pt`) from **anywhere** in the application, including its index page (`index.pt`).

I've tried the following approach but it doesn't work:

`index.pt`:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal">
  <head><title>SampleApp</title></head>
  <body>
     <h2>Title</h2><hr/>
     <a href="#" title="Sign In"
         tal:attributes="href here/signin.html">Sign In</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

`configure.zcml`:

```xml
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:five="http://namespaces.zope.org/five"
       xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser">

  <five:registerPackage package="." initialize=".initialize" />

  <browser:page
          name="signin.html"
          class="bahmanm.sampleapp.implementation.SampleAppUser.SampleAppUser"
          template="templates/manage_addSampleUserForm.pt"
          permission="zope.Public"
  />

</configure>
```

During instance startup, Zope complains:

```
ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/home/bahman/sampleapp/sampleapp.devistan/src/bahmanm/sampleapp/configure.zcml", line 10.2-15.5
    TypeError: page() takes at least 4 arguments (5 given)
```

I also tried adding `for="*"` but Zope poped up the following error when navigating to the application index page:

```
2013-01-08 15:43:26 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1357647206.080.27220840385 http://localhost:8080/sampleapp/index_html
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplateFile, line 130, in _exec
  Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplate, line 79, in pt_render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 113, in pt_render
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 405, in do_startTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 482, in attrAction_tal
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 225, in evaluateText
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: index_html
   - Line 7, Column 3
   - Expression: <PathExpr standard:'here/signin.html'>
   - Names:
      {'container': <SampleApp at /sampleapp>,
       'context': <SampleApp at /sampleapp>,
       'default': <object object at 0x7fa1499cf4c0>,
       'here': <SampleApp at /sampleapp>,
       'loop': {},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {'args': ()},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x7fa134030ba8>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:8080/sampleapp/index_html>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'template': <PageTemplateFile at /sampleapp/index>,
       'user': <User 'admin'>}
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in __call__
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 147, in _eval
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 124, in _eval
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 74, in boboAwareZopeTraverse
  Module OFS.Traversable, line 317, in restrictedTraverse
  Module OFS.Traversable, line 275, in unrestrictedTraverse
   - __traceback_info__: ([], 'signin.html')
  Module zope.component._api, line 120, in queryMultiAdapter
  Module zope.component.registry, line 238, in queryMultiAdapter
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 532, in queryMultiAdapter
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

What am I doing wrong?  To be honest, I believe I'm doing many things wrong :-) as I'm just blind-shooting by reading [Zope 3 apidoc](http://apidoc.zope.org/++apidoc++/ZCML/http_co__sl__sl_namespaces.zope.org_sl_browser/page/index.html) and reading other products' code (like SilvaForum).

I'd really appreciate any hint/help.  TIA,

Comment: What classes does `SampleAppUser` inherit from? You say it inherits from the required classes, but your traceback suggests otherwise.

Comment: `class SampleAppUser(Implicit, Persistent, RoleManager, Folder)`, is what I could understand from the docs.  Should I add anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser pages are separate components altogether. They are not part of the target content type but a separate component altogether.

If all you need is a template (no view), just omit the class directive altogether:

```
<browser:page
    name="signin.html"
    for="*"
    template="templates/manage_addSampleUserForm.pt"
    permission="zope.Public"
    />
```

There is no need to create a `PageTemplateFile` instance manually for that.

It is not entirely clear what you want to do with your link in your template. `` `here/signin.html" `` does not look like a valid TALES expression.  In plain Zope there are no easy tools to generate absolute URLs relative to a site root; perhaps you just want `/signin.html` and not use a TAL expression?

Comment: Thanks.  That solved the index page problem.  Now the index page shows up but when I click on the link I get a "resource not found" error: `<p>Sorry, the requested resource does not exist. Check the URL and try again.</p><p><b>Resource:</b> 1999 GET</p>`.

Comment: @BahmanM.: Looks like your URL wasn't generated properly in the `<a href` tag.

Comment: The edited answer hit the spot; no need for TAL, just `/signin.html`.  Thanks.  The sign-in page has a button that creates the actual user.  Clicking that button pops up another "resource not found" complaining about not being able to find the `action` method.  However I think it's only a problem with my understanding how pages and actions work together.