# Zope 2: What's the difference between "template" and "view"?

Tags: zope

I know, it's a naive question :-)

Originally poped up into my mind over [Zope 2: How to properly “browser:page” to make a page available everywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214808/zope-2-how-to-properly-browserpage-to-make-a-page-available-everywhere/14215186#14215186)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are callable adapters that provide output based on the context and the request.

Templates are callables that render a piece of text based on a template. They are often used in views.

Note that views can return text without using a template:

```
from zope.publisher.browser import BrowserView

class MyView(BrowserView):
    def __call__(self):
        return "Hello world, I am located at {0}".format(self.context.absolute_url())
```

Views can also be used by other Zope code, without themselves being published. Zope code uses a lot of views internally.

Comment: So a `view` handles actions defined in a piece of HTML which is generated by a (or multiple) `template`(s).  And those actions change the underlying model (like `OFS.Folder`), correct?

Comment: They *could* do that, but don't have to. But yes, the context could be a `OFS.Folder`.

Comment: Then why do we need a new layer (`view`)?  I don't understand the purpose of `view`s.  Indulge me a moment in my confusion but I haven't seen a similar pattern in other web frameworks which are usually in the form of Template→HTML→Action→Model.

Comment: Because you can adapt views to different contexts. They are independent of the context and can be registered for additional contexts, *or* you can add additional interfaces to a context to make more views work for it.

Comment: Put a checkbox in a form that adds or removes the `IScreenPresentation` interface from a context, and then the `ScreenPresentationView` view works or doesn't work, for example.

Comment: Because a `view` interacts with `context`, it's not bound to any specific model.  All it needs to know about the model, is its interface, regardless of the implementation.  Am I right?  BTW, is there a (simple) piece of code that demonstrates the use of views alongside templates in action?  Shoot!  I'm good at code reading :-)

Comment: There are *loads* of views defined in the [Plone ecosystem](https://github.com/plone); most packages will have a `browser` subdirectory that is going to be chuck-full of examples.